# Monitor a repository in Jenkins, but don't pull

Tags: git, github, jenkins

Is there an option to monitor a git repository in Jenkins, but not do the pull/clone/fetch upon commit?

- The **Source Code Mangement** set to "Git"
- The **Repository URL** is set to
  git@github.com:name/branch.git
- The **Branch to build** is set to
  origin/1.0

I want the triggering of a build job based upon a commit to the specified branch in the repository, but I don't want the Jenkins build job to do the automatic pull/clone/fetch.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the question. Why would you monitor a repository but not want to fetch it when it is updated? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: There are select changes and setups I want to do before cloning the repo.  So, a change is committed to the repo, a Jenkins build job is triggered, my modifications happen, then the cloning of the repo happens.

Comment: We can only help you if you clearly explain what you are trying to do. "select changes and setups" isn't clear. I still don't understand what your actual goal is.

Comment: I want to clone another repo first which during it's build process does a git clone of the repo where the commit was done.

Comment: This question is completely understandable for me. You have to know how jenkins checks for source code modifications. If you don't, this question isn't meant for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, there is no way to poll a github repository to start a Jenkins task and not download the aforementioned github repository.

Answer (score 3):

While there is no way to poll a github repository to kick off a job without first pulling in the code for that job, you can work around this problem by using the [jenkins multijob plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin) to set up a multi phase job, configured as follows:

- Configure a master job that resides in `WORKSPACE-A`. This job will
  poll the git repo you are monitoring. When a change is made, the job
  will pull the changes (which you won't use) and then proceed with the build, whose steps will be to kick off two other jobs in series.
- Configure a second job to be triggered as the first build phase by
  the master job. This job will reside in `WORKSPACE-B` and it tracks no git
  repository. This job can do any of the pre-configuration you want.
  Because it exists in a workspace different from that of the master
  job, it will not be polluted by the source code from git.
- Configure a third job to be triggered as the second and final build phase by
  the master job. This job may reside anywhere you need it to --
  including `WORKSPACE-A` or `WORKSPACE-B` if that's what you want. You can
  either have this job track the same repo as the master job so that
  the changes are automatically pulled into the workspace, or copy the
  files already cloned from your git repo from `WORKSPACE-A` into this job's
  workspace.

Note: Only the master job should have a build trigger -- the one tied to changes to the git repo. The other two jobs will be triggered externally from the master job.

Answer (score 0):

Let me understand your requirement here.

You want to monitor the repository but not to pull anything: whenever somebody commits into the repo, you want to check the integrity of repo instead of cloning.

I do not see any sense for above requirement; instead of jenkins you can have monitoring in place for the same.

Still you want to achieve this. You can set up a job without specifying any git URL in SCM section, and you can add the following in your execute shell section.

```
git ls-remote <GIT-URL>
```

(Make sure you have the proper permission to do this over the shell).

If you are all good, You will get all branches, tags and pull request info, and then you can decide the exit status.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, no, that was not helpful.   I'm trying to have Jenkins monitor a specific github repo and start a build task based upon a commit to that repo's branch, but I don' want the build task to automatically do the clone.

Comment: I have tested above, You may want to change the strategy to match your exact need.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't poll the github repo, which is my need.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you configure your job to poll every minute, would running this command achieve your goal?

```
git log --since="1 minute ago" | wc -l
```

You would have to pull the repository when setting up the Jenkins workspace, but you could turn off the SCM connection afterwards.